# JQuery Loop Table and remove a href from a td

Tags: jquery

I have a table Structure.

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to write the JQuery Code.

It will be Looping the table and remove the `a tag` from the td except 2nd td.

Comment: Plz take a look at this help article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` for td and `find` a tag and use `removeAttr` to remove href

```
$("#table tr").each(function(index, item){
  $(item).find('td').eq(0).find('a').removeAttr("href");
  $(item).find('td').eq(2).find('a').removeAttr("href");
  $(item).find('td').eq(3).find('a').removeAttr("href");
  $(item).find('td').eq(4).find('a').removeAttr("href");
});
```

```js
$("#table tr").each(function(index, item){
  $(item).find('td').eq(0).find('a').removeAttr("href");
  $(item).find('td').eq(2).find('a').removeAttr("href");
  $(item).find('td').eq(3).find('a').removeAttr("href");
  $(item).find('td').eq(4).find('a').removeAttr("href");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Kindly use it with Table ID, So I can use your code. please don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

this will remove the a tags:

```
$('#table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each (function(index) {
  if(index != 1)
  {
    let str = $(this).find('a').html();
    $(this).html('');
    $(this).html(str);
  }
});  
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d8fz4h1v/

Comment: You have removed all the href. I need to keep 2nd TD Href (Not need to remove). can you please do this for me.

Comment: fixed, look at it now

Answer (score 1):

The [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) `"#table td:not(:nth-child(2)) a"` will loop through all desired links and the [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method will clear them out.

```js
$('#table td:not(:nth-child(2)) a').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry but how does it fail? The snippet does work in the my windows chrome, I can share a screenshot if you'd like. Can you tell how it fails in your machine? Any error messages?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Actually I have complex table structure of NetSuite, that is why your code did not work.

Answer (score 1):

A reduced solution based on [.replaceWith()](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/#replaceWith-function) or [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
$('#table tr>td:not(:nth-child(2)) a').replaceWith((idx, ele) => ele);


$('#table tr>td:not(:nth-child(2))').empty();
```

```js
// $('#table tr>td:not(:nth-child(2)) a').replaceWith((idx, ele) => ele);

$('#table tr>td:not(:nth-child(2))').empty();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/one">One</a></td>
        <td><a href="/two">Two</a></td>
        <td><a href="/three">Three</a></td>
        <td><a href="/four">Four</a></td>
        <td><a href="/five">Five</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```